# Totem pole vs open collector configuration

Tags: digital-logic, open-collector, totem-pole

Can anyone please explain for power consumption view point only whether totem pole or open collector should be preferred with a bit explanation?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please be more specific about your question (click the `edit` button). Different situations have different requirements for both signals and for power.

Answer (score 2):

Totem pole should just about always be preferred if power consumption is the only consideration.

When the output is low, a totem pole output will consume very little current. (If you consider CMOS, the static current can be nearly 0, but since you mention "open collector" rather than "open drain", I assume you are asking about bipolar technologies)

An open collector with a low output voltage will consume current of approximately \$V_{cc}/R\$ where \$R\$ is the resistance of the pull-up used.

When the output is high, either configuration should consume only very small currents.

Comment: Not only the consmption, but also the speed if the output drives a capacitive load.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, of course, but the question specifically asked about "power consumption view point".

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous occasions where an open collector (or open drain) solution is appropriate.

In [I2C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) [and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Management_Bus) [derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Bus), all devices are connected on the bidirectional SDA line.

If totem pole drivers were used, there would need to be some sort of [arbitration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbiter_(electronics)) to select which device can transmit (and there would need to be a way to ensure the output of devices that should not drive the bus were [high impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_impedance)), but that is overkill for a slow speed bus.

Consider a [window comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_detector) made of two comparators with totem pole outputs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx7uUw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here the output is fed to a gate to decode the output because standard totem pole drivers cannot be tied together as there would be [output pin contention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_impedance); however usually power sensing is a relatively slow event (there are always exceptions), so it would be possible to replace a gate with a resistor if these were open collector:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVhHoG.png)</sup>

This admittedly slower, but it is possible there may be numerous such window comparators, and the use of a single resistor to signal a fault when *any output goes low* greatly simplifies a design for a global fault trap. This is known as a [wire-or](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX971-MAX984.pdf) arrangement (a bit confusing in a way - if any window input is out of range the output will go *low*).

As the output transition time would be slow, there can be an issue for digital logic, but that can be solved with a single [schmitt trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger).

So the answer is it is application dependent.

I will note that very early data bus implementations used open collector devices, before the invention of the [tri-state logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic).